# I have an article table that stores the user id, article id and the article view and i want to retrieve the id where they are greater than 50

Tags: mysql

I have an article table that stores the `user id`, `article id`, and the `article views`. I want to get all the users from this table and order them by their total article views `(sum) > 50`.

See the table below.

```
id | user_id | article_id | views
1      2          1          34
2      2          2          26
3      3          3          19
4      3          4          26
5      4          5          40
6      4          6          29
```

I want to get something like this.

```
user_id | views
 2          60
 4          69
```

Comment: Sorry, total gibberish, no clue what you need.  Try another explanation, show the table format and contents, what algorithm you wnat to apply to get your result.  Look at the question itself, and ask yourself if someone who has no idea or your project can help you with the information you provided.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The `views` column - is it storing a space separated list of numbers ( ids )?

Comment: Check this site out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Thanks and well done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to use an aggragating function `sum` to total up the views and then use `group by` to give the desired response.

```
mysql> describe `blah`;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| article_id | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| views      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+




mysql> select * from blah;
+----+---------+------------+-------+
| id | user_id | article_id | views |
+----+---------+------------+-------+
|  1 |       2 |          1 |    34 |
|  2 |       2 |          2 |    26 |
|  3 |       3 |          3 |    19 |
|  4 |       3 |          4 |    26 |
|  5 |       4 |          5 |    40 |
|  6 |       4 |          6 |    29 |
+----+---------+------------+-------+


/* use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to give desired output */
mysql> select `user_id`, sum( `views` ) from `blah` group by `user_id`;
+---------+----------------+
| user_id | sum( `views` ) |
+---------+----------------+
|       2 |             60 |
|       3 |             45 |
|       4 |             69 |
+---------+----------------+
```

To limit the records to above 50

```
mysql> select `user_id`, sum( `views` ) as 'total' from `blah` group by `user_id` 
       having `total` > 50;
+---------+-------+
| user_id | total |
+---------+-------+
|       2 |    60 |
|       4 |    69 |
+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is GROUP BY, SUM() and HAVING

You need GROUP BY to tell mysql that you are grouping entries of the same user together into one entry. You need SUM(views) to tell mysql that all the entries for views for the same user need to be added together. Finally, you need HAVING to tell mysql that there is a condition on the group-by-level that needs to be fulfilled in order to be considered a valid result.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(views) AS views
FROM table GROUP
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(views) > 50
```